# I would like to copy a Dataframe and interpolate the values of this new dataframe to achieve Data Augmentation

Tags: python, pandas

My original dataframe looks like this:

| *No index* | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 1.0 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 1.0 | 0.4 | 0.4 |
| 3 | 0.8 | 0.6 | 0.6 |
| 4 | 0.5 | 0.4 | 0.8 |
| 5 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 1.0 |

And what I want to achieve is the following:

| *No index* | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.0 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| 1 | 1.0 | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| 2 | 0.9 | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 0.65 | 0.5 | 0.7 |
| 4 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.9 |
| 5 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 1.0 |

I would basically like to shift the new dataframe by 1 index, and then compute the average of the two original values. But keeping the values in the last row the same.

Is there someone who can help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rolling_mean` and get values from the last row:

```
out = df.rolling(2).mean().shift(-1)
out.loc[len(df)-1] = df.tail(1).values
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   Value1  Value2  Value3
0    1.00     0.1     0.1
1    1.00     0.3     0.3
2    0.90     0.5     0.5
3    0.65     0.5     0.7
4    0.30     0.3     0.9
5    0.10     0.2     1.0
```

Comment: @Timkowik23. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Hi @Corralien. Yes this solves my problem. Thank you for this elegant answer. Best, Tim